# WRONG Persian Character in FAST REPORT

Tags: .net-core, report, fastreport

I have problem using FastReport in .net core web api.
When export to pdf from this code:

```
  Report fastReport = new Report();
  fastReport.Report.Load($"Report/{installmentReports.ReportName}.frx");

  fastReport.Prepare();
  PDFExport export = new PDFExport();

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    export.Export(fastReport, ms);
    ms.Flush();
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("test") + ".pdf");
  }
```

PERSIAN CHARACTER is not show normally!

[Normal Report from designer preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0TZx.jpg)

[Abnormal Report from CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmZfp.jpg)

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem with Arabic letters. This issue is new to the .NET core version. The .NET 4.x versions has no such issues with RTL languages.

Currently, the only way around is to use HTMLExport instead of PDFExport.